# Can we have index on indexedDb using dart in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, indexeddb

I have tried implementing [Hive](https://docs.hivedb.dev/) for flutter web, but found out that it doesn't provide adding indexes. The underlying indexedDb provided adding [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/index) but Hive doesn't provide (at least I couldn't find any example or docs)

I am trying to implement [idb_shim](https://pub.dev/packages/idb_shim), which has official docs for adding index to database.

When I am trying to add a `dart object` to indexDb using `idb_shim` it throws an error `UnimplementedError: structured clone of other type` for some entries. Following is code to add

```
      IdbFactory idbFactory = getIdbFactory();
      _db = await idbFactory.open(boxName,
        version: 1, onUpgradeNeeded: this.onUpgradeNeeded);
      var txn = _db.transaction(boxName, idbModeReadWrite);
      var store = txn.objectStore(boxName);
      await store.put(value, key);
      await txn.completed;
```

Similarly, when I am trying to read the object, it is in form of `ArrayBuffer` not the JSON object. There is no docs indicating clearly on how to store/read `dart objects` in indexedDb.

```
      var txn = _db.transaction(boxName, idbModeReadOnly);
      var store = txn.objectStore(boxName);
      final value = await store.getObject(key);
      print(value); // ArrayBuffer

      await txn.completed;
      return value as T; // throws error when converting to actual dart-object
```

- Do we need to convert dart-objects to Javascript Objects using `dart:js` package?
- Do we need to store the object in stringified JSON string? In this case index may not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to both issues:

**Do we need to convert dart-objects to Javascript Objects using dart:js package?**

Yes, we need to create different objects with following syntax:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
@anonymous
abstract class JsItem {
  external bool get prop1;
  external int get prop2;
  external String get prop3;
  external String get bulk_data;

  external factory JsItem({int prop2 = 0, String prop3 = '', String bulk_data = '', bool prop1 = false});
}
```

While inserting to `IndexedDB` you can insert the object `JsItem()`.

**Do we need to store the object in stringified JSON string? In this case index may not work?**

I have overcome of this issue by converting most of data (excluding indexes properties) to `JSON` string and inserting into `bulk_data`. Here `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` are indexes.

**Reading the data**

While reading the data form `indexedDB` it comes in format of `LinkedList` map and all properties can be read as `map` properties. So it would be helpful to create a helper function like below:

```
  toDartItem(LinkedMap map){
    return DartItem({ prop1: map["prop1"], 
     prop2: map["prop2"], 
     prop3: map["prop3"], 
     bulk_data: map["bulk_data"], // Convert JSOn to different props as required
    )};
  }
```